# Changing glyphicon on hover (bootstrap)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an icon:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' aria-hidden='true'></span>
```

On hover, I want the glyphicon to change from `heart-empty` to:

```
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart' aria-hidden='true'></span>
```

And then if the user clicks the icon, the button will have the glyphicon `heart` and if the users clicks the icon again, it will put its state back to `heart-empty`.

I have seen this JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GCme2/4/) which on hover, displays an icon, whereas I want it to completely change the icon. I have tried to use the approach in the JSfiddle, but it I cannot get it to do what I want.

Comment: The example in the fiddle is using jQueryUI, whereas you're using bootstrap. The method is the same though - you just need to `toggleClass('glyphicon-heart-empty glyphicon-heart')`. Alternatively you can use CSS alone using the unicode values of the glyphicons directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `content` property of the `:before` pseudo element to be the that of the icon you want.

**Css**

```
span.clicked:before {
  content: "\e005";
}
```

By adding a class when you click the icon you can then apply the new icon code.

**JS**

```
document.querySelector('span').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('clicked')
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/eu6vqka7/2/)

Comment: Thank you, the CSS worked perfectly for me, the JS didn't work for me however, probably missing something on my end. Is there a way to get it state and for it to be remain that until the user clicks the icon again? For example, if the user clicks the icon, it is now `heart`, now, if I go to, say `home.php` and back to `profile.php` where the icons are created, the icons reset to `heart-empty`.

Comment: You could use `localStorage` or a cookie to persist that information. Thats  all on the client though and would suggest something such as "heart'ing" is stored on the server.
Have you looked at the demo i linked to,  that shows a working version with the js

Comment: Yes, I have seen the demo, and I have now incorporated the js into my system, and great news, it works! However, it is a bit glitchy? It takes me two clicks on the icon from it to become from `heart-empty` to `heart`.

Answer (score 0):

You can see an example below

```
<div>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' data-clicked="false" aria-hidden='true'></span> The Heart
</div>
<div>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' data-clicked="false" aria-hidden='true'></span> The Heart
</div>
<div>
<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart-empty' data-clicked="false" aria-hidden='true'></span> The Heart
</div>
```

and javascript part should be like

```
$("div").click(function() {
        var icon = $("span.glyphicon", this);
        var isClicked = icon.data("clicked");
    icon.data("clicked", !isClicked);
}).hover(function () {
    // hover in      
    var icon = $("span.glyphicon", this);
    var isClicked = icon.data("clicked");
    var remCls = isClicked ? "glyphicon-heart" : "glyphicon-heart-empty",
            addCls = isClicked ? "glyphicon-heart-empty" : "glyphicon-heart"
    icon
        .removeClass(remCls)
      .addClass(addCls);
}, function () {
    // hover out
    var icon = $("span.glyphicon", this);
    var isClicked = icon.data("clicked");
    var remCls = isClicked ? "glyphicon-heart-empty" : "glyphicon-heart",
            addCls = isClicked ? "glyphicon-heart" : "glyphicon-heart-empty"
    icon
        .removeClass(remCls)
      .addClass(addCls);
});
```

fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/88nara7m/1/